# Remove rectangle from Progress Indicator

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I tested Progress Indicator in Java 8u40. I get this visual result when I tried to make simple example. Do you know how I can remove the rectangle borders?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `-fx-border-color` value in CSS?

Comment: Yes, it's not working.

Comment: I have the same issue on 8u45, but I see it only if I use `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_CASPIAN)`.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me with no border or other problems (JDK 1.8.0_20ea):

```
    stage.setWidth(100);
    stage.setHeight(100);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
    progress.setMaxWidth(50);
    progress.setMaxHeight(50);

    root.setCenter(progress);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    stage.show();
```

Is this maybe a bug in 8u40?

Comment: Yes, my tests show the border was introduced in 8u40.  I still see it in 8u45.  8u31, 8u25, and 8u20 did not exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the CSS

```
-fx-box-border: transparent;
```

to the progress indicator.

Comment: Can you post code that will generate the screenshot you showed?

Answer (score 0):

I came from the future. The CSS you're all looking for is:

```
.progress-indicator:indeterminate > .spinner {
   -fx-border-width: 0 !important;
}
```

Now my soul can finally rest, knowing that this most vexing regret need not befall this generation